# How to Convert PDF to Excel in java using Apache Poi

Tags: java, excel, pdf, apache-poi

Everyone, I have some 10 pdf file (No Tables in this files) and i need to convert to Excel.

Is there a way to convert to Excel?

By Googling, Using Apache Poi/aspose we can achieve this. but I am not getting proper way(Code link) for this.

How can I do this using Apache POI/aspose. Any help, suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Split your requirement into two parts
1>read from PDF -using **itext**
2>write into xls -using **poi**

Comment: you have a pdf with no table and you want an excel file? What will you put in the table?

Comment: I mean i have some information about the company profile, i need to put it in excel. sory improper question format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the only possible way to do this is using Aspose. Thought we can read the PDF using PDFBox kind of library and write to the excel using apache POI or etc will break the formatting. If we want to convert PDF to Excel with the formatting we need to use aspose.

http://www.aspose.com/

This is a commercial product but you can use the trial version to test your requirement.

http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfjava/Convert+PDF+to+Excel+Workbook

Thanks

Comment: Ya in PDFBox, Im loosing its format. let me try this trial version